# Exception when comparing an (int)double and (int)int

Tags: c++, exception, if-statement, double, int

Hey so i'm using the pdCurses lib and stringStream to calculate and make a 5 character long string that represents a clock. It shows like 00:00, 0:00, 00.00, or 0.000. However when running my function i get an exeption thrown at this part:

```
if((int)time >= 10)
{
    if((int)time >= 60)
    {
        if((int)time >= 600)
        {
```

The exception points to this also Saying there is an access violation:

```
/* verify block type */
            _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));
```

Why is this happening with something as simple as an if statement?  and how can i fix it? **Thanks for any help! =)** Also here's my function:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////    Refresh     ///////////////////////////
void Refresh()
{
      for(int r = 0;r<nrows;r++)
      {
          move(r,0);
          instr((char*)_contents[r].c_str());
      }   // make sure this works later

      // Insert the current time;
      enum{ time_loc_y= 24, time_loc_x= 10 };
      long float time = myStopwatch.ElapsedTime();
      string time_s= "     "; 
      string min;  ss << (int)time%60; ss >> min;
      string sec;  ss << (int)time/60; ss >> sec;

      if((int)time >= 10)
      {
          if((int)time >= 60)
          {
              if((int)time >= 600)
              {
                  time_s.insert(0, min); // 00:00
                  time_s.insert(time_s.begin()+2, ':');
                  time_s.insert(4, sec);
              }
              else
              {
                  time_s.insert(1, min); //  0:00
                  time_s.insert(time_s.begin()+2, ':');
                  time_s.insert(4, sec);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              ss.precision(2); ss << time; //  00.00
              ss >> time_s;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          ss.precision(3);
          ss << time; //  0.000
          ss >> time_s;
      }
      mvinstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, (char*)time_s.c_str());
      refresh();
 }; // end of function
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `ss` upon which you are using both the put (`<<`) and get (`>>`) operators?

Comment: Firstly, what's `long float`? Secondly, if `ss` is `stringstream`, then you can't use `ss` two times in a row the way you use it. The second attempt will result in empty string being read. Thirdly, the problem most likely is heap corruption that happened elsewhere. The code you posted will not be sufficient to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really enough to go on here, but my guess is that the assertion is from the `time_s.insert(0, min)` call that's in the line along with the `if((int)time >= 600)` - the string is performing some reallocation and the heap has been corrupted (maybe by whatever is happening in the loop at the top of the function, but maybe somewhere else entirely).

If you run this in a debugger and have it catch the assertion, what does the call stack look like?

What's happening in:

```
for(int r = 0;r<nrows;r++){ move(r,0); 
                                instr((char*)_contents[r].c_str());}
```

Comment: Heres the call stack that pops up right when i hit the first if:

Answer (score 1):

This is a memory system assertion, it usually is triggered by allocating memory when the heap has already been corrupted.  The trigger was probably this:

```
time_s.insert(0, min);
```

However, the problem is somewhere else--somewhere where you are overwriting memory that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken about what's throwing the exception.  Where is `ss` defined?

NB if you reformat your code to a more canonical style, like

```
if((int)time >= 10){    
    if((int)time >= 60){
       if((int)time >= 600){   
          time_s.insert(0, min);              // 00:00
          time_s.insert(time_s.begin()+2, ':');
          time_s.insert(4, sec);
       } else {
```

with one statement per line, the exception will tell you much more closely which statement caused the problem.