# Exception when comparing an (int)double and (int)int

Tags: c++, exception, if-statement, double, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception when comparing an (int)double and (int)int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013318/exception-when-comparing-an-intdouble-and-intint)

IGNORE THIS POST. ACCIDENTLY REPOSTED

Sorry

Comment: Where did you get the strange idea that it is happening with `if` statement, when your call stack clearly indicates that it happens inside some `std::string` operation?

Comment: Also, what is `long float` supposed to mean? There's no such type in C++.

Comment: Only ask stuff once, that's enough.

Comment: I'm not sure what `instr((char*)_contents[r].c_str())` does. But if its taking `char*` don't pass a `const char* typecasted`. May be its freed inside and when string goes out of scope its deallocated again

Comment: @Griffin: And you're asking the same question twice because....? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013585/exception-when-comparing-an-intdouble-and-intint

Comment: @Griffin: If you want to add additional information, you should edit your previous Q, please do not start a new Q. Editing the same Q will help everyone understand the problem you are facing in a better way and help you out in faster, better way.

Comment: God dammit..>=( I tried editing the old question but it posted a new one... WTF sorry guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((int)time >= 600){   time_s.insert(4, sec);
```

should be,

```
if((int)time >= 600){   time_s.insert(3, sec);  // digit 3 instead of 4
```

From your code, I suppose the string size is `6` characters (0 to 4  and 5th character as `nul`). Inserting 2 digit at 4th position and 5th position would overwrite `nul`.

Do cross verify, as I have made a guess seeing your code.

Comment: What `nul` are you talking about?

Comment: I imagine that he means the [null terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

Comment: But there's no null terminator in `std::string`. On top of that `insert` method does not overwrite anything. It *inserts*, as the name suggests.

Comment: @AndreyT, Christopher is right. I meant `null terminator` (which is at many conventions spelled as `nul`). That's simply the last `0` character.

Comment: @iammilind: Well, again, there's no "null terminator" in `std::string`. `std::string` is a string with stored length, not a null-terminated string.

Comment: @AndreyT, I might be wrong, but my assumption was that why following works: `string s = "hello"; int i = strlen(s.c_str());` ? `c_str()` should return a null terminated character string; isn't it ?

Comment: @iammilind: Yes, but that's irrelevant. `c_str()` does return a null-terminated string, of course. That is the purpose of `c_str()`. However, that does not in any way mean that the controlled sequence in `std::string` is stored in null-terminated form. Moreover, the controlled sequence in `std::string` is not even guaranteed to be stored continuously. In general case, when you call `c_str()`, a separate temporary null-terminated continuous *copy* of the string is made. That *copy* is what you see through `c_str()`.

Comment: When you use methods like `insert` and the like, you are working with the actual controlled sequence stored in `std::string`. And that sequence in not guaranteed to be null-terminated and is not guaranteed to be continuous.